# Using a mask in a data driven display

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

My application displays data on a graph. The graph extracts data from a database and displays a series of points that appear horizontally on the graph. Each point is joined by a line to help the viewer to view the data points. This has worked perfectly until recently when I started to notice the line failing to appear. Interestingly, the line disappears when there are exactly 96 or more data points that are in the database. I've checked the data and it is not a problem with the database.
I have spent 2 days attempting to track down the bug and  found that if I stop the joining line from being a mask, the bug disappears, but then I lose an important visual effect. I suspect the problem might be connected to the use of the mask, but cannot find a similar bug reports online.
Has anyone seen a similar problem or can anyone recommend an approach that I might take to fix the error? I'll be happy to add more code to what I post below, but have not done so as the code is quite complex.

```
            //Draw a backgrond gradient for masking
        var gradientBoxMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        gradientBoxMatrix.createGradientBox(gradientBoxWidth, 400, Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
        backgroundGradient.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFF0000, 0xFFFF00,0x00FF00, 0x00FFFF, 0x0000FF], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
            [0, 64, 128, 192, 255], gradientBoxMatrix);
        backgroundGradient.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, gradientBoxWidth, 400);
        backgroundGradient.graphics.endFill();
        backgroundGradient.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        lineChartContainer.addChild(backgroundGradient) ;

        backgroundGradient.mask = myLine;
        myLine = new DataPoint_Line;

        //Set the line for masking and drawing
        myLine.cacheAsBitmap=true;
        lineChartContainer.addChild(myLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a max size for your graphical object once it becomes a bitmap (cacheAsBitmap = true). Remove that and you'll have a slower to render but visible graph :)

Break the graph into many images and "glue" them when you need to scroll or at least re-render the whole graphics object each time you scroll.

Comment: I tried removing cacheAsBitmap from both the background image the is being masked, and from the line that masks, but that did not work.
I'm intrigued by the idea of gluing together several dynamically generated images. Are you able to point me to example code where this is illustrated? Thanks for you reply!